# Moving object in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am stuck at a point which I don't know what to do. I am learning the basics of using the canvas element so I gave myself a little assignment. I want to place a circle on the canvas which can be pushed forward by pressing a button. So each time a button is pressed, the circle should move forward 10px. But now I am stuck for a while and I can't figure out what I do wrong. (I am also new into programming in javascript and programming overal).

This is the code I have so far

```
    <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button onclick="animationStep()" id="startAnimation" style="width:200px; height:50px; color:"green";">Press here to move</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300"
        style="border: 1px dotted black">
</canvas>
<script>


   function drawDisc( x,y,r ) {
      theContext.beginPath();
      theContext.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,false);
      theContext.closePath();
      theContext.fill();
   }

   function startDrawing(canvasId) {
      var canvasElement = document.getElementById(canvasId);
      var drawingContext = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
      return drawingContext;
   }

   var theContext = startDrawing("myCanvas")

   var x = 100; 

   function animationStep(){
       while( x <= 400 ) {
          x = x + 10;
          theContext.clearRect(0,0,500,300); 
          drawDisc( x, 100, 30 );
          console.log("animated");
       }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I look in the console log, it immediately execute the animation 36 times. I think it's stuck in the while loop but I cant figure out how to get this to work properly. Maybe I am overlooking something simple?

Thanks in regard!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the while loop.

So

```
function animationStep(){
   while( x <= 400 ) {
      x = x + 10;
      theContext.clearRect(0,0,500,300); 
      drawDisc( x, 100, 30 );
      console.log("animated");
   }
}
```

should be

```
function animationStep(){
      x = x + 10;
      theContext.clearRect(0,0,500,300); 
      drawDisc( x, 100, 30 );
      console.log("animated");
}
```

Comment: That did it! Wow, that it would be that easy. Was the problem that my code was hanging in the while loop and only showed the "last" possible loop?

Comment: Your while loop incremented x to 410 and when you called it a second time the while loop would do nothing because x is bigger than 400.

Comment: Hey, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.